# Python 2.7 Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get my head around this. I haven't found too many good examples online where I can clearly see what is going on with multiprocessing. I'm using python 2.7 What I'm trying to do is have a python script listen for input and then act on it if received while still doing time sensitive tasks. So I can't have the listening interrupt the flow of the rest of the script.

Here's my setup:

```
def listen_process():
    while 1 < 2:
        print "blue"

q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen_process())
q.start()

print red
```

I would expect my output to look something like this:

```
blue
blue
red
blue
...
```

instead all I get is

```
blue 
blue
blue
...
```

I only get red when I interrupt it.

In the real code I'm making an os.system call to a new file that essentially does the while loop, but I can't see why calling a different file would make any difference...

Comment: The code you have provided would not output anything

Comment: You want, `target=listen_process`, not `target=listen_process()`.

Comment: Did you mean `print "red"`? Also I have no idea why it would print `blue` as `1 > 2` evaluates to `False`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lays out in this line:

```
q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen_process())
```

What happens is that the expression *target=listen_process()* doesn't assign the function *listen_process* to the keyword argument *listen*, but rather it assigns *the result of the function's call* to *target*.

This implies that *listen_process* is being called in the main thread before the second one is ran. This is, of course, not what you want.

Change that line for:

```
q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen_process)
```

And you'll be okay.

Comment: Thank you very much! I never would have noticed that. I've been staring at this for hours Thank you!